# Compiled aar has Kotlin source file .kt inside

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, aar

I used a kotlin file inside a java project. After generating aar unzipping I saw the source file .kt inside the aar package.

Comment: what is problem with that?

Comment: I have .kt file with and .class in aar package opening the .kt file opens the source code which is a problem because it is an encryption util file

Comment: `aar`  is your own developed library

Comment: yes but compiled library should not include source code files

Comment: if you have configured as the module content roots or source roots than it can be modified. –

Comment: Is that a thing that happens when compiling for debug only? Including sources is maybe intentional in that case. Though I don't see source listed in https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#aar-contents - Also you don't have encryption if it breaks when someone can see the source or a compiled class since you can decompile those as well. Change your security model.

Comment: It's not intentional. Please show how your project is configured and built.